# How to tune bandwidth in machine learning kernel model?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, hyperparameter, rbf-kernel

Gaussian kernel

$k(x,y) = \exp(-\lVert x-y \rVert^2/\sigma^2)$

has a hyperparameter $\sigma$.

I know **grid search cross validation**, but this would require a lot of computation since computational cost of kernel method scales with the number of samples to the power of 2.

Comment: The only way to tune the bandwidth of the kernel (or any other parameters) is via cross-validation. You can do this with grid search, random search or better with more advanced optimization techniques (look for Hyperopt in python). If you stick with grid search, try just a few values for σ, then try other values close to the optimal identified and repeat this procedure until you are happy with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do kernel regression or Gaussian process regression you can use alternative approaches. They are better as they allow direct optimization instead of Grid search. I suggest you to try two approaches:

1. **Maximum likelihood estimate.** If you have a sample $D = (X, \mathbf{y}) = \{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i = 1}^n$ for inputs $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and output $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ then you can compute kernel matrix: $K = \{k_{ij}\}_{i, j = 1}^n$ with $k_{ij} = k_{\sigma}(x_i, x_j)$. Then the log likelihood is:
   $$
   L(D, \sigma) = -1/2 \left[det(K) + \mathbf{y}^T K^{-1} \mathbf{y} \right].
   $$
   If you maximize $L(D, \sigma)$ w.r.t. $\sigma$ you get a maximum likelihood estimate for $\sigma$ for Gaussian process regression. The likelihood function has derivatives and all that staff, and optimization problem is pretty good (but not convex).
2. **LOO cross-validation**. For kernel methods you can calculate leave-one-out cross validation faster. See the question [Gaussian process regression: leave-one-out prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/gaussian-process-regression-leave-one-out-prediction)

Note, that for both these approach we need to inverse $K$, so the computational complexity of each optimization step is $O(n^3)$.

However, there are some faster approximation calculation see e.g. [Random Fourier Features](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~sip/work/report_kernel.pdf) - an easy to implement approach that allows you to handle high computational complexity. In this case complexity scales as $m^2 n$, where $m$ is a parameter. Нou can use $m$ significantly smaller than $n$.