# Analytical Leave-one-out prediction variance for Kriging

Tags: cross-validation, gaussian-process, prediction-interval, kriging

I make extensive use of Kriging (Gaussian Process regression) methods in my work especially using the leave-one-out error calculation that you can get from the Gram matrix.

#### Background:

To compute the LOOCV error estimate without brute-force solving $N$ equations, you can do the following:

Briefly, following from J. D. Martin and T. W. Simpson. Use of Kriging Models to Approximate Deterministic Computer Models. AIAA journal, 43(4):853–863, 2005, especially Eq 20 (and thereabouts):

Let $F$ be the Vandermond matrix of the polynomial trend function. Let $K$ be the Gram matrix (ie. the kernel evaluated at the construction points) and let $K^{-1}$ be its inverse. Let $c$ be the polynomial coefficients. Let $f$ be the construction values. Define:

$$
Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{K^{-1}_{1,1}} &    & 0 \\\ 
 & \ddots &  \\\
0 & & \frac{1}{K_{N,N}^{-1}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then,
$$
e = Q\left ( K^{-1}Fc - K^{-1}f \right )
$$
and then the total error is
$$
    E = \frac{||e||}{\sqrt{N}}
$$
or
$$
    E_{rel} = \frac{||e||}{||f||}
$$

### My Question

I make extensive use of $E$ as a general error estimate and even more so, $e$ as a point-wise *estimate* of the error. Both have proven to be very useful and insightful.

But for Kriging, I would also like to examine not the error but how well its prediction uncertainty bounds the error. I can obviously do this with brute force but I suspect there is a similar treatment as above to get the prediction variance.

Does anyone know of it or can they point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

#### Similar Questions

I note that [156161](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/gaussian-process-regression-leave-one-out-prediction) also asks about the LOOCV but they are asking about *noise* and not the *prediction* variance. The referenced Dubrule 1983 paper was also very informative about the above equations but did not answer the prediction variance question.

Comment: I suspect this paper may be of some use https://jmlr.org/papers/volume17/14-540/14-540.pdf it seems to have formulae for both the predictive mean and variance (page 11/12?), but it has been a long day and I am pretty much mentally negligible at this point!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot more reading into other answers including the aforementioned Dubrule 1983 [1], the answer is actually that the prediction variance is just the diagonal of $Q$. See [1] eq 8. I also numerically tested this and it works to about 1e-5 error (so more than machine precision but reasonable)

I hope this helps someone else!

[1] O. Dubrule. Cross validation of kriging in a unique neighborhood. Journal of the International Association for Mathematical Geology, 15(6):687–699, 1983.